# Inject a Stateless EJB in a SessionScoped CDI Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I wonder what happens with the injected EJB-Proxy, when the SessionScoped CDI bean was passivated and then activated. Is there a null ref? Or is the EJB "reinjected"? Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 6.6.3. (Passivation capable dependencies) of CDI spec states that the container guarantees Stateless beans are Passivation capable whether you declare your stateless bean serializable or not.

Section 6.6.5 of the specs states that an error occurs at deployment if a passivating scope ('@SessionScoped' for example) declares a dependency to a non-passivation capable dependency.

How the container handles the reactivation is implementation dependent. It can make the stateless bean serializable, or the proxy serializable and the reference to the bean, when the proxy is deserialized is updated.

Comment: >`the reference to the bean, when the proxy is deserialized is updated` - I haven't investigated every other proxy of EJB implementations, but conceptually I don't think a proxy holds a reference to an actual stateless bean, but just code to fetch it from a pool. Namely, every other call to the same proxy may go to a different bean instance, so it wouldn't make much sense for a proxy to retain a reference to a specific instance.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer of maress; since a Stateless bean is for the client in fact stateless, the container does not necessarily have to serialize anything for it.

Every other call to a stateless bean can go to a different bean instance anyway, or every other call can cause a new bean instance to be created (which is the default behavior in WildFly 8 if I'm not mistaken).

As maress mentioned, technically the proxy can be made serializable, but the proxy typically does little more than fetch the actual bean* from a systemwide pool (which can be of zero size) and delegate all method calls to that.

*) *As a technical detail; the proxy may not call the actual bean directly, but call into an interceptor chain before the actual-actual bean is called*